# Load GetX translations from Firestore using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

How can I load translations from Firestore and then use them for GetX translations/internationalization?

I want to have a language collection inside two documents (US & DE) that contain all the string value translations.
Therefore instead of this...

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'hello': 'Hello World',
        },
        'de_DE': {
          'hello': 'Hallo Welt',
        }
      };
}
```

I want something like this...

//Get data from Firestore as `dataFromFirestore_US` & `dataFromFirestore_DE`

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          dataFromFirestore_US,
        },
        'de_DE': {
          dataFromFirestore_DE,
        }
      };
}
```

I tried loading data from Firestore and get the error message:

`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/ testing/errors`

**To get this error:**

I have a LanguageController.dart file that loads the language as follows:

```
    final languages = LanguageModel().obs;
    
      Future getLanguages() async {
        QuerySnapshot data =
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("languages").get();
        data.docs.forEach((doc) {
          if (doc.id == "en") {
            var enLang = "'void': 'GO ONLINE'";
            Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            for (String key in data.keys) {
              enLang = '$enLang, "${key.toString()}": "${data[key].toString()}"';
            } 
            languages.value.en = enLang;
            en.value = enLang;
          }
    
        });
      }
```

The LanguageModel.dart looks like this:

```
    class LanguageModel {
      dynamic en;
      dynamic se;
    
      LanguageModel({this.en, this.se});
      Map<String, Map<String, String>> toJson() {
        return {
          "en": en,
          "se": se,
        };
      }
    }
```

The Translation part looks like:

```
  static final locale = Locale('se', 'SE');

  static final fallbackLocale = Locale('en', 'US');


  static final langs = [
    'Swedish',
    'English',
  ];

  static final locales = [
    Locale('se', 'SE'),
    Locale('en', 'US'),
  ];
  @override
  // TODO: implement keys

  @override
 
  final LanguageController l = Get.find();
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': l.languages.value.en, 
        'se_SE': seSE, 
      };
  // Gets locale from language, and updates the locale
  void changeLocale(String lang) {
    final locale = _getLocaleFromLanguage(lang);
    Get.updateLocale(locale!);
  }
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: give us a snippet of the code that throwed that error for you

Comment: I have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get everything working well and can switch between languages loaded from Firestore, I hope this helps anyone else wanting to do the same.

**SOLUTION**

**1. Firestore collection, documents, and data**

Create a *collection* called *languages*, I need English and Swedish
therefore I have 2 documents called *en* and *se* containing the
language data as strings such as: `hello: 'Hello'`

**2. LanguageController.dart (Get data from Firestore)**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart'; import
'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

    class LanguageController extends GetxController {
      RxString language = "Swedish".obs;
    
      RxMap<String, String> langEN = <String, String>{}.obs;
      RxMap<String, String> langSE = <String, String>{}.obs;
    
      void updateLanguage(String data) {
        language.value = data;
      }
    
      Future getLanguages() async {
        //Get all languages in languages collection
        QuerySnapshot data =
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("languages").get();
    
        data.docs.forEach((doc) {
          if (doc.id == "en") {
            final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            for (String key in data.keys) {
              langEN['${key.toString()}'] = '${data[key].toString()}';
            }
          } else if (doc.id == "se") {
            final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            for (String key in data.keys) {
              langSE['${key.toString()}'] = '${data[key].toString()}';
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

**3. languages.dart**

```
    import 'dart:ui';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    
    import '../controllers/LanguageController.dart';
    
    class Languages extends Translations {
      // Default locale
      static final locale = Locale('se', 'SE');
    
      // fallbackLocale saves the day when the locale gets in trouble
      static final fallbackLocale = Locale('en', 'US');
    
      // Supported languages
      // Needs to be same order with locales
      static final langs = [
        'Swedish',
        'English',
      ];
    
      // Supported locales
      // Needs to be same order with langs
      static final locales = [
        Locale('se', 'SE'),
        Locale('en', 'US'),
      ];
      final LanguageController l = Get.find();
    
      @override
      Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys =>
          {'en_US': l.langEN, 'se_SE': l.langSE};
    
      // Gets locale from language, and updates the locale
      void changeLocale(String lang) {
        final locale = _getLocaleFromLanguage(lang);
        Get.updateLocale(locale!);
      }
    
      // Finds language in `langs` list and returns it as Locale
      Locale? _getLocaleFromLanguage(String lang) {
        for (int i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
          if (lang == langs[i]) return locales[i];
        }
        return Get.locale;
      }
    }
```

*If anyone has any issues comment and I will try and help out.*

Comment: Great Idea, I load all the translations from local files first so I ensure there is always text.

Then I load in translations from firestore and use the "appendTranslations" method in get to override the current local translations. That way I can use the native get translations utils like normal.

Also I record in firestore all translations in a document but i use maps so i can have a bit more flexibility.

But it was great inspiration. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, can you share your code for loading locally first as that is a great idea?

It would be great to see you integrate that into my example above  